# Magento2 Not Found Error

Tags: magento2

**Magento2 Not Found Error**

When I'm click on further links then not found error occurs.
Also when login into admin panel I'm also getting not found error.

Answer (score 3):

First solve this by other solution if still not work just Run Command In Terminal

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf (or open file manually in your editor)

Change below code

```
From:

<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>

TO:

<Directory "/var/www/html"> 
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
   AllowOverride All 
   Require all granted 
</Directory>
```

Then restart apache2 by following command

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Done!

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same problem and have just fixed it.

My solution is:

```
sudo -i #then enter your root password
chmod -R 777 <magento_installation_dir>/
```

You **may** have to restart apache2.

That's it.

Comment: Note: You might get fired if you did this on production. Please find another way to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Check your base URLs, you can also check that you've set AllowOverrides properly for Apache.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html#apache-help-rewrite

Comment: Have you enable apache rewrite module ?

Answer (score 0):

Please enable apache mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Please open .htaccess file from root

Uncomment below line

```
SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Magento2 has to fix some problems, but you can make I dirty fix to work around these troubles. If you append "index.php" on your host-name resp. put it in between the hostname and the given `request-uri` you will come in the admin-panel and find other thinks. This is not a problem about the directive `SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer` in the .htaccess or enabling the rewrite_mod in the apache-conf or throw a `.htaccess`, I believe that you already have done all this thinks. Just check the "allow override - directive" in apache2 to allowed `.htaccess` during your development stuff, the rest should be enabled by default.

If you can call the admin-panel using my advice, you have to build a `.htaccess` with proper rewrite rules. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

What is the web server that you are using to install Magento2?

If you are using Apache2, please make sure you have right Apache permission. You can open this fine /etc/apache2/envvars with root permission (for Linux only)

Find and change following lines:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=your_linux_user
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=your_linux_group
```